Power BI Dynamic Title - how to return "All" if all slicer options are selected
The Title I want is: when I select every province, the title would show the same as nothing selected.
For example, when nothing is selected, the title looks like this: Weekly Report - All Provinces:

If I select everything, right now the title looks like this:

But I want it return the same as above: "Weekly Report - All Provinces"
The measure I created:
Title =
"Weekly Report - "
    & IF (
        NOT ( ISFILTERED ( DIMENSION[Province] ) ),
        "All Provinces",
        IF (
            ISFILTERED ( DIMENSION[Province] ),
            CONCATENATEX ( VALUES ( DIMENSION[Province] ), DIMENSION[Province], "," )
        )
    )

Can someone kindly take a look and help me fix this? Thanks so much in advance!!

Title =
var province_list= IF(
    ISFILTERED('Dimension'[Province]),
    CONCATENATEX(
        VALUES('Dimension'[Province]),
        'Dimension'[Province], ", "
    ),
    "All Provinces"
)
var distinct_count = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Dimension'[Province]), ALL('Dimension'[Province]))
var comma_count = LEN(province_list) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(province_list, ",", ""))


return
    SWITCH(
        TRUE(),
        comma_count = 0 && province_list = "All Provinces", "Weekly Report - All Provinces",
        comma_count + 1 = distinct_count, "Weekly Report - All Provinces",
        "Weekly Report - " & province_list
    )


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
